# Last record of resultset displayed again and again by jsp in strut1

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to display resultset jsp,but in that last record in resultset get displayed again.Records get fetched by action class but i think logic:ierate is not working.I cant solve this problem.I am sending my whole code. Please help me, how can I resolve my problem?

```
 public class ReportsAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action

 {

  public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception
   {


    String target = null;
    ReportActionForm f=(ReportActionForm) form;
    String loanAmount=f.getloanAmount();
    String Status=f.getstatus();
    String City=f.getCity();
    String LoanFor=f.getLoanType();
    String BankName=f.getBankName();
    String Team=f.getTeam();
    String RegDate=f.getRegDate();
    String RegDate2=f.getRegDate2();
   Logger l1=Logger.getLogger("my");

        l1.info("city : "+City); 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=(Connection)  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://SERVER:3306/dsa","dexpertuser","Dspl_2014");

        ArrayList<ReportBean> list=new ArrayList<ReportBean>();
        ReportBean rb=new ReportBean();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        l1.info("city : "+City);          


        String cmd="select * from DSA.lead where  City='"+City+"' or Status='"+Status+"' or LoanFor='"+LoanFor+"' or BankName='"+BankName+"' or Team='"+Team+"'";

        Statement st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(cmd);


    while(rs.next())
    {
        rb.setUserName(rs.getString("UserName"));
        rb.setCity(rs.getString("City"));
        rb.setLoanAmount(rs.getString("LoanAmount"));
        rb.setStatus(rs.getString("Status"));
        rb.setBankName(rs.getString("BankName"));
         l1.info("city IS: "+rs.getString("UserName")); 
       list.add(rb);

    }
 if(list.isEmpty())
       {
          target="Yes"; 
       }

       else{

    target="success";
    request.setAttribute("list1", list);
    }

     return mapping.findForward(target);  
}
```

}

Otput jsp page:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>


    <table border="1">


        <tr><th>User Name :</th><th>City</th><th>Loan Amount</th><th>Status</th><th> Bank Name</th></tr>
        <logic:iterate name="list1" id="A" > 
        <tr><td><bean:write name="A" property="userName" /></td>
            <td><bean:write name="A" property="city" /></td>
         <td><bean:write name="A" property="loanAmount" /></td>
         <td><bean:write name="A" property="status" /></td>
        <td><bean:write name="A" property="bankName" /></td></tr>
         </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
        </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you make your post more clearer,I read thrice but unable to understand your problem and requirement

Comment: Post your problem more clearly, like: facing problem with fetching the correct data or problem with displaying the correctly fetched data or you need a good logic for iterating the data?

Answer (score 0):

You are not ***cleaning up*** the things after using the resultset. That  might cause a problem.

```
  while(rs.next())
  {
     rb.setUserName(rs.getString("UserName"));
     rb.setCity(rs.getString("City"));
     rb.setLoanAmount(rs.getString("LoanAmount"));
     rb.setStatus(rs.getString("Status"));
     rb.setBankName(rs.getString("BankName"));
     l1.info("city IS: "+rs.getString("UserName")); 
     list.add(rb);

  }
  //Clean-up environment
  rs.close();
  st.close();
  con.close();
```